# Xamarin forms signed apk

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I am using Xamarin trail version.I build one sample application with two entry fields and one button field in xamarin cross platform. When i build and run the app with the USB cable it works fine without any problems.But when i tried to  install the app using signed apk, The app installed successfully but it is not running.Is there any problem with xamarin trail version

Answer (score 0):

Have to **"aligned"** your .apk?
Else the app will load and terminate abruptly

Answer (score 0):

Do some research on how to create APKs.
If I remember correctly when you build in debug and deploy to the device Xamarin is doing some under the hood signing.
Actually you should see two APKs in your debug folder - one will run while other does not.
Xaramin has some documentation on this. I believe if you do a search related on how to build and deploy an app to Google Play you will find some insight.

Answer (score 0):

did you set keystore file to xamarin.android project?
If not, to set it.

select `xamarin.android` project and click mouse right button.

go to options/android package signing/

On this window you can set key store file for debug and release mode.
[image]